# Mysql - Set timeout for Alter table & Update scripts

Tags: mysql, query-timeout

On MySQL 5.7.
I would like to prevent all alter table scripts \ update scripts that are taking longer than 10 minutes to run.

Is it possible?

I've tried to set **MAX_EXECUTION_TIME** and it does work but only for SELECT queries. I still could execute a long update\alter query.

Comment: Why do you want to block ALTER TABLE that takes more than 10 minutes? Are you aware there are free tools like [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html) that allow you to continue accessing the table while it applies the alter?

Answer (score 0):

No straightforward way.

You *could* write code to perform `SHOW PROCESSLIST` every minute, ignore system actions that run 'forever', locate only "alter/update" commands (but not scripts), check the "Time", and issue "kill pid".

If this is a team effort, I would (instead) implement a review process for every "alter/update script" to try to fix scripts before attempting them.

Keep in mind that killing a command after 10 minutes:

- Wasted some resources for 10 minutes.
- May have to spend more than 10 minutes in `ROLLBACK` (in the case of `UPDATE`), again wasting resources.
- And the desired task is still left to be done.